# Child processes sort input from parent, send output via pipes. Why am I getting duplicate words?

Tags: c, loops, pipe, children, fork

This is probably going to be a fairly complex problem.  Here is the situation:

I'm trying to write a program that takes two command line arguments: # of children to spawn, and the name of a file with words separated by spaces.

This program takes the file, parses the words, MUST use fputs to put each individual word, round robin style, into the pipes (as in first word goes into first pipe, second word goes into second pipe, etc.) and attaches these pipes to the correct spawned children.

After the parser parses the words and fills the pipes, # of children child processes are spawned, and each receives one pipe from the parser, containing the words.  The pipe is then mapped to stdin to use with the sort() process, and the stdout output of the sort() process is then attached to a second set of pipes (#children *2 again).  These output pipes from the children are then taken to a suppressor part of the program which then has to take one word off the top of each pipe, fgets MUST be used, find which is the smallest, print it, discard it, then replace that discarded word with the second word from that pipe, find which is the smallest again, until all the pipes are empty.

I know there is likely a far easier way, but I have decided to create a char* array that is #children in length so from each pipe, when I pull a word, I can put it in the array to loop through and compare.  When the smallest is found, the contents at the index of the smallest word is set to NULL after the word is printed, and the next iteration of the overall WHILE loop makes sure to fill that one index of the array with the next word from the corresponding pipe.  The WHILE is supposed to run until all cells in the array are NULL (there are no more words coming from any of the pipes).

So far, I've only had the WHILE loop iterate 3 times, and have discovered that the word array gets its first set of words, it finds the smallest, prints it, sets it to NULL, but during the second iteration the NULL contents of the array is replaced by a new word that is NOT a new word.  It is a duplicate from another pipe.

I do not believe it's a problem with parsing and putting the words into the pipes; I've tested it extensively and it seems to do alright up until the sort() process.  After the sort process I'm afraid I can only guess at what is going wrong.  I have spent many many hours trying to troubleshoot it, to no avail.

So, now some code.  I will post the children spawning segment, then the suppressor.  Since this is still a work in progress it is a bit messy and there are several variables that are only really used in debugging.  I apologize in advance!!

Spawning of the Children (mapping of pipes to stdin/stdout and creation of sort() processes):

```
//Collection of children need to be created specified by numChildren
int count;
for(count = 0; count < numChildren; count++){
    printf("Count: %d\n", count);

    switch((p = fork())){

    case -1:
        perror("Could not create child");
        exit(-1);

    case 0:
        printf("Entering child\n");
        close(0);
        close(1);
        dup(pipefds[count*2]);
        dup(pipefds_two[(count*2)+1]);
        execlp("/bin/sort", "sort", (char*)NULL); // (char*)NULL
        break;

    default:
        //parent case -- p holds pid of child
        printf("I am the parent, PID: %d\n", getpid());
        child = wait(&status);
        printf("pipefds_two: %d\n", pipefds_two[count*2]);
        printf("Waited on child %d\n", child);

        break;
    }

}
```

Finally, the Suppressor:

```
//Suppressor - Reads one word from each pipe, compares, prints largest.  Gets next word from that one pipe, compares, prints largest.  
//Suppressor deletes duplicate words
//Reads from pipefds_two[count*2] position
char* words[numChildren];
int index, cont=1;
char* smallest; 
int smallestIndex;
int checker;
int duplicateCount = 0;
int kindex;
char* temptwo;
int length;
int nullCount = 0;
int counter = 0;

for(kindex = 0; kindex < numChildren; kindex++){ //Initializes array with beginning values
    FILE* sortOutput = fdopen(pipefds_two[kindex*2], "r");
    fgets(buffer, PIPE_BUF, sortOutput);
    words[kindex] = strdup(buffer);
    fflush(sortOutput);
    close(pipefds_two[(kindex*2)+1]);
}
while(counter < 3){ //This is where it prints out lowest values each "round", gets new words, and gets rid of duplicates
    for(index = 0; index < numChildren; index++){
        if(words[index] != NULL){ //Searches for first value in array that's not null to be "lowest" value
            smallest = words[index];
            smallestIndex = index;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Suppressor WHILE \n");
    nullCount = 0;
    printf("smallest word assigned: %s\n", smallest);
    printf("smallest index %d\n", smallestIndex);
    for(index = 0; index < numChildren; index++){ //need to loop through each pipe and pull a word, THEN compare them all!
    printf("Suppressor FOR (index: %d word:%s)\n", index, words[index]);
        if(words[index] == NULL){ //Fills in a NULL gap in the array with a new word from the corresponding pipe
            FILE* sortOutput = fdopen(pipefds_two[index*2], "r");
            fgets(buffer, PIPE_BUF, sortOutput);
            words[index] = strdup(buffer);
            fflush(sortOutput);
            printf("the word which replaces a NULL: %s\n", words[index]);
        }
    }
    for(index = 0; index < numChildren; index++){ //COMPARE ALL VALUES NOW THAT IT IS POPULATED
    printf("compare FOR loop index: %d\n", index);
        if((index != numChildren) && (words[index] != NULL) && (index != smallestIndex)){
            printf("IF statement, (current arrayWord: %s)(smallest: %s)\n", words[index], smallest);
            checker = strcmp(smallest, words[index]); 
            //printf("checker\n");
            if(checker > 0){
                smallest = words[index];
                smallestIndex = index;
                printf("New smallest assigned: %s\n New Smallest Index: %d\n", smallest, smallestIndex);
            }else if(checker == 0){
                printf("Same word\n");
                words[index] = NULL;
                duplicateCount++;
            }else{
                printf("ArrayWord is larger, smallest staying the same\n");
            }

        } if(index == numChildren-1){ //reached the end of the list
            printf("The smallest this round is: %s\n", smallest);
            words[smallestIndex] = NULL;
        }
    }
    for(index = 0; index < numChildren; index++){ //Check for removed words!
    printf("Checking if entries are null in array: index %d\n", index);
        if(words[index] == NULL){
            nullCount++;
            printf("words at index null num: %d\n", nullCount);
        }
    }
    //check to see if everything is null
    counter++;
}
```

At any rate, if you have read this far, I thank you sincerely.  This problem has plagued me for at least a week and any suggestions/comments are greatly and tremendously appreciated!

Edit:

As far as I can tell, the parser splits it up properly and I have seen the words arrive at the children processes properly.  Additionally I did a bit more testing last night and the words that the suppressor pulls out at first are the proper words.  For example, if your word list is

camera about couch whisker yes vodka umpire price yield

then when it goes into the pipes assuming you have 3 children, it would be: camera whisker umpire in the first, about yes price in the second, and couch vodka and yield in the third.

When these are sorted, the first output pipe should contain camera umpire whisker, the second with about price yes, and the third with couch yield vodka.  The suppressor then pulls out camera, about, couch, and compares them.  It seems to work well up until that point and through testing I have found that it does, in fact, pull out the correct first word from the sorted lists.  The smallest would be about, which the suppressor then sets to null in the comparison array, but this is where the problem happens.

The problem comes with the second iteration.  After one word is pulled from each pipe and the comparison made, the one word is then set to NULL so the next iteration it gets replaced by a new word from the correct pipe.  For whatever reason, at this step, when about is being replaced by (what should be) price, it is actually being replaced by couch (which is the word in the third pipe).

It seems like it's pulling from the wrong pipe but based on my code I cannot see how that is possible.

Edit 2!!

I have narrowed it down considerably.  Through clearing the buffer with bzero(buffer, PIPE_BUF); prior to reading additional contents from the pipes (within the suppressor portion, after detecting if an array contents is NULL), and some changing of the way my FILE* sortOutput is declared (one global variable as opposed to redefining it every iteration through the loop) it now grabs new words.  But, when a pipe runs out of words, it still for some reason compares the empty index contents with a word (which means the empty index contents is the smallest!)

How do I prevent that?

Comment: Can you narrow it down? This is a fairly large amount of code and text!

Comment: Strategy for finding complex bugs: Remove complexity from your code, part after part, and check whether the bug persists. You could, for example, use only a single child process, or remove the 'parsing' part, or remove the multiprocessing part.

Comment: Yes, I apologize.  I'm fairly certain the bug is within the suppressor.  I am updating my post now to reflect it.

Comment: Ok to narrow it down even futher, I have cleared the buffer in the suppressor section prior to retrieving additional words from the pipes.  I know now that fetching additional words from the pipe is failing!  I'll update the post to reflect this